# Calculate distance from point p to high dimensional Gaussian (M, V)

Tags: matlab, distance, gaussian, ellipse

I have a high dimensional Gaussian with mean M and covariance matrix V. I would like to calculate the distance from point p to M, taking V into consideration (I guess it's the distance in standard deviations of p from M?).

Phrased differentially, I take an ellipse one sigma away from M, and would like to check whether p is inside that ellipse.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `V` is a valid covariance matrix of a gaussian, it then is symmetric positive definite and therefore defines a valid scalar product. By the way `inv(V)` also does.

Therefore, assuming that M and p are column vectors, you could define distances as:

```
d1 = sqrt((M-p)'*V*(M-p));
d2 = sqrt((M-p)'*inv(V)*(M-p));
```

the Matlab way one would rewrite `d2`as (probably some unnecessary parentheses):

```
d2 = sqrt((M-p)'*(V\(M-p)));
```

The nice thing is that when V is the unit matrix, then `d1==d2`and it correspond to the classical euclidian distance. To find wether you have to use `d1` or `d2`is left as an exercise (sorry, part of my job is teaching). Write the multi-dimensional gaussian formula and compare it to the 1D case, since the multidimensional case is only a particular case of the 1D (or perform some numerical experiment).

NB: in very high dimensional spaces or for very many points to test, you might find a clever / faster way from the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of V (i.e. the principal axes of the ellipsoid and their corresponding variance).

Hope this helps.

A.

Comment: This seems to be it. Thank you!

Comment: The thing has a name: [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). :-)

Answer (score 3):

Consider computing the probability of the point given the normal distribution:

```
M = [1 -1];             %# mean vector
V = [.9 .4; .4 .3];     %# covariance matrix
p = [0.5 -1.5];         %# 2d-point
prob = mvnpdf(p,M,V);   %# probability P(p|mu,cov)
```

The function [MVNPDF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mvnpdf.html) is provided by the Statistics Toolbox

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm totally off, but isn't this the same as just asking for each dimension: Am I inside the sigma?

PSEUDOCODE:

```
foreach(dimension d)
    (M(d) - sigma(d) < p(d) < M(d) + sigma(d)) ?
```

Because you want to know if p is inside every dimension of your gaussian. So actually, this is just a space problem and your Gaussian hasn't have to do anything with it (except for M and sigma which are just distances).

In MATLAB you could try something like:

```
all(M - sigma < p < M + sigma)
```

A distance to that place could be, where I don't know the function for the Euclidean distance. Maybe dist works:

```
dist(M, p)
```

Because M is just a point in space and p as well. Just 2 vectors.
And now the final one. You want to know the distance in a form of sigma's:

```
% create a distance vector and divide it by sigma
M - p ./ sigma
```

I think that will do the trick.

Comment: This solution will not work, since it does not take into consideration the covariance (the ellipse is "slanted", in a way). Thanks though!